# Property in viewstate different on one page to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

This is really weird error i'm getting and i'll try and explain as best I can.

I have two pages - Page 1 (form) and Page 2 (completed page)

From page 1 I put a variable into a database and then do a server.transfer to page two like so...

```
Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", True)
```

On page 2 I then grab the variable called `paymentOnHold` which is set on Page 1 and goes into the database...

Here is how I set `paymentOnHold` on Page 1

```
Public Property paymentOnHold() As String
    Get
        Dim _paymentOnHold As Object = ViewState("paymentOnHold")
        If _paymentOnHold IsNot Nothing Then
            Return CType(_paymentOnHold, String)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            ViewState("paymentOnHold") = value
        Else
            ViewState("paymentOnHold") = Nothing
        End If
    End Set
End Property

...

paymentOnHold = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Here's how I grab the value on Page 2...

```
Dim myValue As String

 If TypeOf PreviousPage Is Page1 Then

        myValue = DirectCast(PreviousPage, Page1).paymentOnHold

End If
```

In my development environment where the databases are local the value in the DB and the value on page 2 both match - as you would expect...

In live environment the DB value is 3 or 4 seconds different (before) the one on Page 2 - even though I do not reset it or anything?

This has been driving me crazy for the last few hours and cannot work it.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe Server.Transfer() starts off a whole new page life-cycle (wiping out or at least obscuring the old Page1).  So, where is the `PreviousPage` variable coming from when you're in Page2?  PS - I don't see you interacting with a database, did you write a custom ViewState?

Comment: @ebyrob - `Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", True)` sends the query string and forms collection to the new page. `ViewState` is part of the forms collection as `__VIEWSTATE`.

Comment: @KarlAnderson That would make sense if he was doing `foo = Page2.ViewState("paymentOnHold")`.  But instead he's casting **something** to `Page1`.  I don't see how even shared viewstate would allow both `Page1` and `Page2` to exist simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue of saving the view state in first Page (form-1)

In asp.net Page lifecycle

```
  1. Initalization (controls raise their Init event)
  2. Load ViewState (Only on post back)
  3. Load PostbackData 
  4. Load
  5. Raise PostbackEvent
  6. Save View State
  7. Render
```

Server.Transfer()  stops rendering the current page and starts rendering another one.That's why Server.Transfer() cannot be used to redirect to pages served by another server.

If you are doing Server.transfer before Event--> 6. Save View State you are not saving viewstate on the form-1

**Solution**

Response.redirect and session cache, as it is intended to exist per user and across multiple pages in the application.

Comment: Hi Shaz, thanks for the information - you are correct with this - I was using server.transfer which created the new lifecycle and it was simply updating the DB on Page_Load again of page 1 and then not saving the new value to viewstate - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `ViewState` in this manner is a brittle solution, because `ViewState` is not intended to exist outside of the scope of the page it was initiated in, much less passed between pages, which I realize you are not quite doing, but you are getting dangerously close to doing it.

The better approach is to use `Session` cache, as it was intended to exist per user and span multiple page requests.

Try this:

To store in `Session`, do this:

```
Session("PaymentOnHold") = [Date].Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

To retrieve a value from `Session`, do this:

```
' First check to see if the value is in Session cache or not
If Session("PaymentOnHold") IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Everything in Session cache is stored as an object so you need to cast it to get it out
    Dim datePaymentOnHold As DateTime = TryCast(Session("PaymentOnHold"), DateTime)
End If
```

Now the `Session` value will be available no matter how you navigate to pages (`Server.Transfer` or `Response.Redirect`).

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the info - I have just tried to implement the suggestion but still the Session is a different value - very strange behavior!